# Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindPairs' of undefined - React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a simple component in React with Coffeescript and Node. However, it keeps throwing back this error:

```
Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindPairs' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

index.coffee:

```
express = require('express')
JSX     = require('node-jsx').install()
React   = require('react')
TestApp = require('../components/Test.react')
router  = express.Router()

# home page
router.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
  React.renderComponent (TestApp {}), document.getElementById('test')
  res.render 'index', title: 'Example'

module.exports = router
```

Test.react.coffee:

```
React = require('react')

TestApp = React.createClass
    render: ->
      p "Hello!"

module.exports = TestApp
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  #test 
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do a few things:

1. Install the ReactDOM package (`npm install react-dom`).
2. Require ReactDOM.
3. Wrap the `require()` statement for your component in `React.createFactory()`.
4. Render the component with `ReactDOM.render()` instead of `React.renderComponent()`.

Observe:

```
express  = require('express')
JSX      = require('node-jsx').install()
React    = require('react')
ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
TestApp  = React.createFactory(require('../components/Test.react'))
router   = express.Router()

# home page
router.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
  ReactDOM.render (TestApp {}), document.getElementById('test')
  res.render 'index', title: 'Example'

module.exports = router
```

See [the React blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html#react-without-jsx) for an explanation.

Comment: Number 3 is a very important step. I wasn't using that and after modifying the code, the app worked. +1 for that :)